# Tracing page loading in Apache

Tags: javascript, php, apache, localhost, vagrant

So, I am copying a file hierarchy from a hosted application to my local machine. The hierarchy absurd, and after copying the http.conf file, the page loads, but not the JavaScript. It can't find the location.

Apparently there is some mechanism that overrides the DocumentRoot, like some sort of ad hoc routing.

I can't even find an `.htacces` file.

Is there anything in Apache that can suppress or alter the directives in `http.conf`?

Comment: just .htaccess files, and further httpd.conf-level stuff. "later" directives will replace/modify earlier ones.

Comment: My issue ultimately had to do with custom filetypes in the `AddType` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this. In my case, the application was meant to load a custom filetype, but instead was loading the default `.html` because there was an `index.html` in the directory. Once I deleted the empty `index.html` the `index.custom` file loads.